Integrate Shaka player into web application via webpack config
I have an existing typescript application with Shaka 3.2.1 integration. Now I am facing some issue with subtitle, so I want to use the uncompiled version of shaka and edit the library.
From Shaka documentation we can use the uncompiled version of shaka by using the following scripts in HTML.
    <script src="node_modules/google-closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
    <!-- Deps file: -->
    <script src="dist/deps.js"></script>
    <!-- Shaka Player uncompiled library: -->
    <script src="shaka-player.uncompiled.js"></script> 

How can we integrate the uncompiled version of Shaka via Webpack config?
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance
